# Updating multiple queries in useMutation Apollo-client without refetching them

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I'm executing this mutation in my NewBook component:

```
const [addBook] = useMutation(ADD_BOOK, {
update: (cache, response) => {
  cache.updateQuery({ query: ALL_BOOKS }, ({ allBooks }) => {
    return { allBooks: allBooks.concat(response.data.addBook) };
  });
},
refetchQueries: [{ query: ALL_AUTHORS }, { query: ALL_GENRES }],
options: {
  awaitRefetchQueries: true,}});
```

Instead of having to refetch those two queries, I'd like to update them like ALL_BOOKS - but could not find any example in the docs. Does anyone know a way to accomplish that?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you need to update? Add new authors and genres?

Comment: Yes exactly. When a new book is successfully added, if its genre or author wasnt in the db before, they are added before the new book is saved. Instead of refetching the queries to update the cache, I'd like to add two more update functions, so I can use the book returned from the server (which has the new genre added as well as the new author added) in order to updated the cache.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is make multiple cache updates based on response data.

Once you add your new book to the query, the next step is to fetch all authors.

```
 cache.updateQuery({ query: ALL_BOOKS }, ({ allBooks }) => {
    return { allBooks: allBooks.concat(response.data.addBook) };
  });
 //Get all authors
 const existingAuthors = cache.readQuery({
       query: ALL_AUTHORS,
       //variables: {}
 });
  //If we never called authors, do nothing, as the next fetch will fetch updated authors. This might be a problem in the future is some cases, depending on how you fetch data. If it is a problem, just rework this to add newAuthor to the array, like allAuthors: [newAuthor]
 if(!existingAuthors.?length) {
  return null
}
```

The next thing is that we need to compare the new book's author with existing authors to see if a new author was added.

```
//continued
const hasAuthor = existingAuthors.find(author => author.id === response.data.createBook.id)
//Double check response.data.createBook.id. I don't know what is returned from response

//If author already exists, do nothing
if(hasAuthor) {
return null
}

//Get a new author. Make sure that this is the same as the one you fetch with ALL_AUTHORS. 
const newAuthor = {
...response.data.createBook.author //Check this
}

cache.writeQuery({
            query: ALL_AUTHORS,
            //variables: {}
            data: {
              allAuthors: [newAuthor, ...existingAuthors.allAuthors]
            },
          });
```

Then continue the same with ALL_GENRES

Note:

- If you called ALL_GENERES or ALL_BOOKS with variables, you MUST put the SAME variables in the write query and read query. Otherwise Apollo wont know what to update
- Double check if you are comparing numbers or strings for authors and genres
- Double check all of the variables I added, they might be named different at your end.
- Use console.log to check incoming variables
- You can probably make this in less lines. There are multiple ways to update cache
- If it doesn't work, console.log cache after the update and see what exactly did apollo do with the update (It could be missing data, or wrong variables.)
- Add more checks to ensure some cases like: response.data returned null, authors already fetched but there are none, etc...